# Event triggering after subscription

Tags: c#, events, timer, event-handling

I have a class that contains a queue and a form that contains a listbox.

When the user opens the form it gets all of the accumulated objects from the queue and shows them in the listbox. While the form is open as soon as the queue gets a new item it notifies the form of the new item via a custom event.

After closing the form the data will accumulate again.

*My problem is the following:* As soon the form is subscribed to the notification event it should dump all of the queue to the form and keep dumping it as long as someone is subscribed to the event. **It should not wait until another item is added to the queue.**

One solution would be to use a timer to check if there are any subscriptions to the event and then dump it. It is not much but i would be wasting resources with the timer.

It would seem to be better if the form's subscription to the event could itself trigger the event. The app is very modular and modules communicate through events to a eventNexus and then the nexus notifies everyone who needs to know.

Since an event is an object as well, it should be possible to accomplish something like this but I did not manage to find any links.

Comment: Can you please post your code here.

Comment: Don't use a timer.  Simply initialize the listbox from the queue.  Only use the event to add new queue items.

Comment: too much and too much complications to add the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can customize the adding and removing of event handlers in the code of the event itself by using the `add` and `remove` statements:

```
private EventHandler onMyEvent;
public event MyEventHandler MyEvent
{
    add
    {
        // run when event handler is added ( += )
        onMyEvent = (MyEventHandler)Delegate.Combine(onMyEvent, value);

        // Add additional, custom logic here...
    }

    remove
    {
        // run when event handler is removed ( -= )
        onMyEvent = (MyEventHandler)Delegate.Remove(onMyEvent, value);
    }
}
```

Here you can add your own code to trigger actions upon adding or removing your event handler.

Comment: I think that this might be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This might also solve some other problems as well and reduce me a ton of code in another place. Thanks

Comment: Is it maybe possible to get the object that subscribed to the event inside the add accessor?

Comment: FOUND IT !! 

Delegate[] x = onMyEvent.GetInvocationList();

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't on before, but I'm glad you found it out by yourself!

Comment: Why use `Delegate.Combine()` instead of `+=` ?

Answer (score 0):

For timer your can try with this code

```
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

    // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

    // Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
    aTimer.Interval = 2000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

Your function

```
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Your treatment
    }
```

Comment: timers a quick and dirty solution. if I start using them every it gets tought, in time, the application will get very bloated.

Comment: o i inderstand your technical need